# Water flow through a ventilated orifice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, flow

Before I begin, please excuse the rushed and poor schematic made in haste.
I am not very knowledgeable in fluid dynamics and was curious when I observed the scenario below.

A water droplet of mass *M* falls upon a surface with an orifice of diameter *D<sub>O</sub>* with depth *h<sub>O</sub>* into the material. It is then connected to a passage way with vents of diameter *h*. Initially, it is observed that the water does not flow through the orifice. However, if the orifice diameter *D<sub>O</sub>* is big enough then the water droplet will flow down it. So the question is, At what *D<sub>O</sub>* value will this occur? Also, will this be any different if the vents on the side of the surface were sealed off.

[image]

Comment: It appears that the magnitude of $h_0$ will not matter if it is large enough compared to orifice diameter. Assuming that the surface on which the drop rests is flat, only two parameters appear to determine the value of $D_0$ at which the drop will flow down into the orifice: weight of the drop $W$ and surface tension $\sigma$. Then, on dimensional grounds, $D_0\sim W/\sigma$, where the constant of proportionality must be determined from an experiment or other means. Of course if the ends of the vent were closed it would affect this estimate, but I don't know how.

Comment: I see! So its the surface tension that is stopping the droplet of water from flowing through the orifice. So when the weight then overcomes this, water will flow? Also, why would ho not matter if it is large enough. What happens if it is comparable to the orifice diameter.

Comment: I may have been wrong about that. Since the drop is only in contact with the edge of the hole, the value of $h_0$ perhaps won't matter at all. Nevertheless it would be interesting to do an experiment where $h_0\ll D_0$ (for eg. the cylinder is made of sheet metal) and see what happens. And yes, surface tension is the only factor that can prevent the droplet from flowing into the orifice.